Reducing the spaces before-after subsections and a table/figure environment
Working on a conference paper that limits number of pages to 10 on an LNCS template.
Run out of the limit my about 3 pages. I am working to reduces content, but being careful not to eliminate important details.
I noticed very wide (unused) space between subsections and table/figure enviroment, that I would like to minimise to make space for more text.
MWE:
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % dummay text 

\begin{document}
%
\title{Contribution Title}

\author{First Author\inst{1} \and
Second Author\inst{2}}

\institute{ABC \and
XYZ
}
%
\maketitle              

\section{Main Section}
\subsection{Section A1}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Table Type Styles}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Table}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Table Column Head}} \\
\cline{2-4} 
\textbf{Head} & \textbf{\textit{Table column subhead}}& \textbf{\textit{Subhead}}& \textbf{\textit{Subhead}} \\
\hline
copy& More table copy$^{\mathrm{a}}$& &  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{$^{\mathrm{a}}$Sample of a Table footnote.}
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\subsection{Subsection A1.2}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}


Outuput:

N.B: This behaviour is also observed between 2 \subsubsection.

Don't use \begin{center}…\end{center} inside table or figure environment, but \centering. The center environment adds extra vertical space.

Off-topic: I would recommend to avoid a lot of horizontal and i.e. vertical lines. See the booktabs manual(s) for more information about nice and good readable tables.

@cabohah thank you, \begin\end{center} commented out in my document. The space didn't seem to reduce anyway.

I'm sure (and I've even tested): It does. BTW: You should not manually reduce spaces. 1. The publisher does not like it, if you change the predefined spaces. 2. floats like table can float and if you, e.g., manually add a negative \vspace, this would be wrong if the table would float to another position. BTW2: h placed table/figures usually need more space than t or b placed. So removing h could also help. But I've not tested this with llncs.

@cfr With \centering instead of center the tabular moves. Not enough to have more text in the page, but it moves. And on other pages, this could be relevant. Note, that llncs uses twoside by default and therefore \flushbottom. So it stretches vertical spaces, if there is not enough space for one more text line. And it uses \widowpenalty/\clubpenalty=10000, which can result in extra stretching. BTW: The instruction explicitly ask for not changing the spacing.
